# Js implement something like protocol delegate in swift

Tags: javascript, delegates

Is there something like the protocol delegate in js??  something like:

```
class a{
    somefunction();//<<== Is called from here
}

class b{
    class_A = new a();

    somefunction(){//Code is implemented here
        //Do something
    }
}
```

Comment: JavaScript is an untyped language and as such you can't declare a protocol. But of course you can implement the delegate design pattern. What is the delegate and what the delegating class in your example code?

Comment: I have looking how to implement something Like the delegate desing pattern, but Im new in js, in this example the a class is the delegating class, and the b class is the delegate, thus the b class implements a method that is declared in the a class.

Comment: Can you give a short description of what you practically want to achieve?

Comment: @IIXIII I posted a pattern similar to the one you have in your example. However, if you can articulate what you are trying to achieve,  le_m will provide you with a better answer.

Comment: I have a js than implements html stuff and other things(lets call class a), and other js with a socket instance(class b),  A instance B to make the connection when a button is clicked, etc, but I need a way than B warns A than something happen(the socket send something). Hope this is enough to  explain my case. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this

```js
class a {

  constructor() {
    this.b = 100000;

    this.a = {
      *[Symbol.iterator]() {
        let pre = 0,
          cur = 1
        for (;;) {
          [pre, cur] = [cur, pre + cur]
          yield cur
        }
      }
    }

  }

  get more() {
    var items = new b(this.a, this.b);
    return items.some;
  }

};

class b {

  constructor(a, b) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    let k = 1;
  }


  get some() {
    for (let n of this.a) {
      if (n > this.b)
        break
      console.log(n)

    }
  }
}


var other = new a();
console.log(other.more);
```